Ubuntu Studio desktop won't load after 24.04 upgrade
Ubuntu Studio desktop won't load after upgrading to 24.04. It just leaves me in the tty virtual console screen:

I tried a lot of commands such as sudo apt update, sudo apt full-upgrade, sudo apt install --reinstall

You can try starting display manager using this command
systemctl start display-manager.service


Says "Failed to start display-manager.service: Unit display-manager.service not found"
